# Heroku deploy fails after upgrading to bootstrap 2.0.1 via twitter-bootstrap-rails gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, asset-pipeline, twitter-bootstrap

UPDATE:

this error is shown during `git push heroku master` :

```
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
       Running: rake assets:precompile
       rake aborted!
       couldn't find file 'twitter/bootstrap'
       (in /tmp/build_2pmsvze33th3e/app/assets/javascripts/application.js:9)

       Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile:primary
       (See full trace by running task with --trace)
       Precompiling assets failed, enabling runtime asset compilation
       Injecting rails31_enable_runtime_asset_compilation
       Please see this article for troubleshooting help:
       http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails31_heroku_cedar#troubleshooting
```

I upgraded Bootstrap 2 layout to 2.0.1 by following this [guide](https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails/wiki/Upgrading-Guide).  After that I get this error deploing to Heroku :

```
2012-02-23T23:12:09+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error ('twitter/bootstrap.less' wasn't found.
2012-02-23T23:12:09+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-02-23T23:12:09+00:00 app[web.1]:   (in /app/app/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap.css.less)):
2012-02-23T23:12:09+00:00 app[web.1]:     7:     /%title gitwatcher.com
2012-02-23T23:12:09+00:00 app[web.1]:     8:     = csrf_meta_tags
2012-02-23T23:12:09+00:00 app[web.1]:     9:     = stylesheet_link_tag "vendor",       :media => "screen"
2012-02-23T23:12:09+00:00 app[web.1]:     10:     = stylesheet_link_tag "application",  :rel => "stylesheet"
2012-02-23T23:12:09+00:00 app[web.1]:     11:     = stylesheet_link_tag "http://jqueryui.com/repository/tags/latest/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css", :media => "screen, projection"
2012-02-23T23:12:09+00:00 app[web.1]:     12:     / 
2012-02-23T23:12:09+00:00 app[web.1]:     13:     :css
2012-02-23T23:12:09+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/layouts/application.html.haml:10:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_haml___2608554683581233975_52490540'
2012-02-23T23:12:09+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-02-23T23:12:09+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-02-23T23:12:09+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /] miss
2012-02-23T23:12:09+00:00 app[web.1]:   Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
2012-02-23T23:12:09+00:00 app[web.1]: Rendered shared/_watch-list-tab.html.haml (4.5ms)
2012-02-23T23:12:09+00:00 app[web.1]: Rendered shared/_watch-list-table.html.haml (30.2ms)
2012-02-23T23:12:09+00:00 app[web.1]: Rendered home/index.html.haml within layouts/application (101.7ms)
2012-02-23T23:12:09+00:00 app[web.1]: Compiled vendor.css  (3ms)  (pid 1)
2012-02-23T23:12:09+00:00 app[web.1]: Compiled css3-github-buttons/gh-buttons.css  (0ms)  (pid 1)
2012-02-23T23:12:09+00:00 app[web.1]: Compiled jquery_carousel/carousel.css  (0ms)  (pid 1)
2012-02-23T23:12:09+00:00 app[web.1]: Compiled application.css  (2ms)  (pid 1)
2012-02-23T23:12:09+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 858ms
```

Previously I got an existing Rails 3.1.3 app already working with Bootstrap 2 layout on Heroku Cedar.

Any idea ?

Comment: Weird that it's looking in `/app/app/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap.css.less` - did you mean to have nested app folders like that?

Comment: no, that's come from heroku logs. I don't know how to get rid of that,  clearly seems a path error/duplication but in previous bootstrap-2 deploy ( via https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails gem ) didn't happen and moreover, locally it works fine ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the following file app/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap.css.less and enjoy.
Soruce https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails/issues/123

Answer (score 2):

I also moved   gem "twitter-bootstrap-rails" outside the assets group and that works!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this issue by simply moving gem "twitter-bootstrap-rails" out of the :assets block and putting it at the top of my gemfile.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

Simply by comment out the following line in Gemfile :

```
#gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails', :git => 'http://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails.git'
```

and using `gem "twitter-bootstrap-rails", "~> 2.0.1.0"` then running `bundle update`

To be complete, my previous failing branch was :

```
-  revision: a5d67d23afeaa76eb52c6f87d55ff407f9c753f2
-    twitter-bootstrap-rails (2.0.1)
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was to remove this line in application.css

```
*= require twitter/bootstrap
```

Se https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails/issues/123

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround for errors during runtime asset compilation is to use the [asset_sync](https://github.com/rumblelabs/asset_sync) gem.