# heroku stopped working after I added google maps API, javascript & edited my layout

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-maps, twitter-bootstrap, heroku

My app is working on my local machine but was working on Heroku, but after I pushed it after adding **Google Maps** & played around with my **Twitter Bootstrap** layout it stopped working on Heroku.

I'm getting this error in my Heroku Logs:

```
ActionView::Template::Error ('twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap.less' wasn't found.
```

I'm fairly new to RoR & am not sure if  my Google Maps script to my application.html.erb & show.html.erb

### application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<![endif]-->
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", :media => "all" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
  <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[I PUT MY API KEY HERE]&sensor=false"> </script>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
.
.
.
```

### show.html.erb

```
<script>
var myCenter=new google.maps.LatLng(<%= @hikingtrail.latitude %>, <%= @hikingtrail.longitude %>);

function initialize()
{
var mapProp = {
  center:myCenter,
  zoom:10,
  mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);

var marker=new google.maps.Marker({
  position:myCenter,
  });

marker.setMap(map);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>


<% provide(:title, @hikingtrail.name) %>
<!-- <p id="notice"><%= notice %></p> -->
.
.
. 

    <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="map">
      <a target="_blank" href='https://maps.google.ie/maps?q=<%= @hikingtrail.address %>'> Open in GoogleMaps </a>
      <br />
      <div id="googleMap" style="width:100%;height:300px;"></div>
    </div>
.
.
.
```

### Heroku Logs

```
2013-04-03T17:54:36+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 3.2.12 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:51640
2013-04-03T17:54:36+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2013-04-03T17:54:36+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2013-04-03T17:54:36+00:00 app[web.1]: => Call with -d to detach
2013-04-03T17:54:36+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 193.1.209.100 at 2013-04-03 17:54:36 +0000
2013-04-03T17:54:36+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by HikingtrailsController#index as HTML
2013-04-03T17:54:37+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered hikingtrails/index.html.erb within layouts/application (80.3ms)
2013-04-03T17:54:37+00:00 app[web.1]: WARN: tilt autoloading 'less' in a non thread-safe way; explicit require 'less' suggested.
2013-04-03T17:54:38+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2094ms
2013-04-03T17:54:38+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-04-03T17:54:38+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error ('twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap.less' wasn't found.
2013-04-03T17:54:38+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-04-03T17:54:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   (in /app/app/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap_and_overrides.css.less)):
2013-04-03T17:54:38+00:00 app[web.1]:     5:   <!--[if lt IE 9]>
2013-04-03T17:54:38+00:00 app[web.1]:     7: <![endif]-->
2013-04-03T17:54:38+00:00 app[web.1]:     8:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", :media => "all" %>
2013-04-03T17:54:38+00:00 app[web.1]:     6: <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
2013-04-03T17:54:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/hikingtrails_controller.rb:11:in `index'
2013-04-03T17:54:38+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-04-03T17:54:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:8:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__2890293300082615835_33779640'
2013-04-03T17:54:38+00:00 app[web.1]:     9:   <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
2013-04-03T17:54:38+00:00 app[web.1]:     10:   <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDDXT3NtHX42AZZapNvA6-Dj3xls_YhfT0&sensor=false"> </script>
2013-04-03T17:54:38+00:00 app[web.1]:     11:   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
2013-04-03T17:54:38+00:00 app[web.1]:
```

Comment: which gem are you using for bootstrap ?

Comment: This https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails/issues/123 and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9423067/heroku-deploy-fails-after-upgrading-to-bootstrap-2-0-1-via-twitter-bootstrap-rai may help

Comment: i'm using `twitter-bootstrap-rails (2.2.6)`, i just have `gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'` in my Gemfile.  I checked my GitHub & this was the same version which was working a few days ago on Heroku

Comment: Thanks Charles, I tried the solutions on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9423067/heroku-deploy-fails-after-upgrading-to-bootstrap-2-0-1-via-twitter-bootstrap-rai but none of them worked, I'll have a close look at github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails/issues/123 & see if that fixes it.

Comment: none of these solutions worked for me :(

Comment: try to bundle install in production this will update your Gemlock.file by bundle install --without test development

Comment: thanks but that didn't work either, I ran `heroku run bundle install --without test development` but app still down

Comment: shrikant I just did a `git push` & I noticed that by running `bundle install --without test development ` it added over 5000 files / 27mb to my **vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems** folder.  DO you know why it would do this? Thanks